# Transform API data and fetching every 60 seconds [react]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, react-hooks

Hi I'm currently having problems with formatting data I'm receiving from an API

---

Should I use reduce instead of forEach?

Here is the desired output, an array of objects with just the titles and prices:

```
[
{
  title: "Meter",
  price:"9.99"
},
{
  title: "Plan One",
  price:"11.99"
}
]
```

Here is how I am getting the data, setting it, refetching it every 60 seconds:

```
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);

  const formatProduct = (products) =>{
    let result = [];
        products.forEach((product)=>{
         if(product.variants['price'] !== "0.00"){
           result.push({product["title"],product.variants[0]["price"]})
         }
      })
      return result
    }

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const axiosResponse = await axios(`https://www.today/products.json`);
      setProducts(formatProduct(axiosResponse.data.products));
    };

    const reFetchData = setInterval(() => setProducts(fetchData()), 60000);
    return () => {
      clearInterval(reFetchData);
    };
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding object to the `result` array you have to specify the name of props. Also you've missed index of `variants` when you compare a price:

```
 const formatProduct = (products) =>{
    let result = [];
    products.forEach((product)=>{
         if(product.variants[0]['price'] !== "0.00"){ //index 0
             result.push({
                 title: product["title"],  // specify the prop name
                 price: product.variants[0]["price"]
             })
         }
    })
    return result
}
```

There is another problem in your code. What happens if `variant` doesn't contain any item? I would check array length and use `filter` and `map` functions:

```
const formatProduct = (products) => {
    return products
        .filter(p => p.variants.lenght>0 && p.variants[0]!=="0.00")
        .map(p => {title: p.title, price: p.variants[0].price});
}
```

Another problem is how you call `setProducts(fetchData())` in the interval function. You shouldn't call `setProducts()` because you're already calling it in `fetchData()`. So it has to be:

```
const reFetchData = setInterval(() => fetchData(), 60000);
```

Comment: thank you for pointing out those problems and suggestions. I completely forgot I needed to index into variants to receive the price correctly